# PHP Database search display

Tags: php, database, sqlite

To give you an understanding of what I'm working on. I'm working on a project where on my school campus you can navigate around. For example a room can be called J2626 or J2617 etc... The thing is that when a user Is using my website I only want it to type in the exact name of the room to be able to display anything. Right now it doesn't work like I want it to.
For example: if you only type in J in the search field, it will display all rooms that start with J.

Here is my code right now:

```
<?php

$fileName = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "../../db/bth_nav.sqlite";

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $argument = $_GET['page'];
    $argument = "%" . $argument . "%";

    $db = new PDO("sqlite:$fileName");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM bth_nav WHERE name LIKE (:nameOwner) OR owner LIKE (:nameOwner);');
    $stmt->execute(array($argument));
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (empty($res)) {
        header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['index.php']);
    }
?>

<div class = "formObjectSearch">

    <?php foreach ($res as $val) { ?>
            <div class = "infoTab">
                <h2><?= $val['name']; ?></h2>
                <p>Guidance: <?= $val['info']; ?></p>
                <p>Whos sitting here?: <?= $val['owner']; ?>
            </div>
            <img class = "buildingImage" src = "img/<?= $val['image']; ?>"
                <?php
      }
}
                ?>
    </div>
```

I've tried making diffrent if statements but with no success. So what I need help with is that I only want the user to be able to search for a correct room name and not be able to only search for J and display everything.

**Update**

Here is my index.php:

I used this link, because Code sample didn't want to work: [index.php code](https://codeshare.io/71tJq)

Here is my building.php:

Samer here: [building.php code](https://codeshare.io/AgkPL)

And the the new search.php with help:

Same here: [search.php code](https://codeshare.io/uTSxO)

I get these errors right now:

Notice: Undefined index: index.php in /path/incl/files/search.php on line 19

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/incl/header.php:7) in /path/incl/files/search.php on line 19

My header.php code:

Same here: [header.php code](https://codeshare.io/rKOYo)

My config.php code:

Same here: [config.php code](https://codeshare.io/1i3C4)

My footer.php code:

Same here: [footer.php code](https://codeshare.io/3cds9)

Comment: `$argument = "%" . $argument . "%";` Don't add percent signs around your argument?

Comment: Replace `LIKE` with `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understanded you correctly and if you want to search for all rooms with starting letter `J`, you need to change your arguments.

**Explanation:**

`'%J%'` - searches for selected field, where is `J` letter.

`'%J'` - searches for selected field, where `J` is the last letter.

`'J%'` - searches for selected field, where `J` is the first letter.

**Try to change your argument like that:**

```
$argument = $argument . "%";
```

**UPDATE**

Fixing your if statement:

```
if (empty($res) OR $res == null) {
   header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['index.php']);
}
else {
   echo '<div class = "formObjectSearch">';
   foreach ($res as $val) {
        echo '<div class = "infoTab">';
        echo '<h2>'.$val["name"].'</h2>';
        echo '<p>Guidance:'.$val["info"].'</p>';
        echo '<p>Whos sitting here?:'.$val["owner"].'</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<img class="buildingImage" src="img/'.$val['image'].'" />';
   }
   echo '</div>';
}
```

**OR**

**You can try to replace empty, with:**

```
if ($res->rowCount() > 0) {
  // if founded
} else {
  // header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['index.php']);
}
```

Comment: My question got answerd in the comment section. I removed all the "%" and it works like I want to now. But how can I change my if statement so that If the user only typed in J, it will be redirected to "index.php"? Because right now my if statement does not work.

Comment: Still no luck with your if statement. Maybe it does not work because of my search form that looks like this
<form class = "search" name = "search" action = "building.php" method = "get">
                    <input class = "myInp" type = "text" placeholder="Search.." name = "page" required>
                    <input class = "mySub" type = "submit" value = "search">
                </form>

Comment: That is in my index.php and it looks the same in building.php. With that if statement my url is still: building.php?page=J

Comment: Still no luck after adding the else after if and putting the formObjectSearch in it. Still the same URL building.php?page=J

Comment: Did you tryed latest updated answer? Because i founded some errors in your original code

Comment: I updated my question, maybe that will help you have a better understanding?

Comment: Your updated answer gave this error:

 Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on array in /path/incl/files/search.php on line 18

Comment: @kreqq_ try replace your header location url with simple ``header('Location: http://google.com');`` just to check if header is working. And dont use (empty).

Comment: Did not work, it still takes me to the same URL, 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/incl/header.php:7) in /path/incl/files/search.php on line 19

Comment: @kreqq_ make sure you have in every php file closing and opening php tags. ``<?php ?>``and in your ``header.php`` change ``<title><?= $title ?></title>`` to ``<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>``and always use ``;`` after end of variable

Comment: Still does'nt work, check my question I have updated the code links and added two more at the bottom(config and footer). I still arrive at the same URL

Comment: Yes, With the code I have in the links in my question, these are the errors I get,  Notice: Undefined index: index.php in /path/incl/files/search.php on line 19 And Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/incl/header.php:7) in /path/incl/files/search.php on line 19.

Comment: @kreqq_ there is a error in your header: ``header('Location: 'https://google.com']);`` remove ``]`` and second ``'``. It must look something like that: ``header('Location: https://google.com');``

Comment: @kreqq_ and remove white spaces before and after ``<?php`` and ``?>``

Comment: I still get this error, 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/incl/header.php:7) in /path/incl/files/search.php on line 19.  What do you mean with remove white spaces before and after <?php ?>?

Comment: @kreqq_ empty lines before ``<?php`` and after ``?>``. Try adding a call to the ``ob_start();`` function at the very top of your script and ``ob_end_flush();`` at the very end of the document.

Comment: The ob_start(); and ob_end_flush(); Made it work! Thanks so much for all the help @Tauras. Everything works like it should now, and I have learned a bunch from this and with your help. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck in coding